# Don't show onbeforeunload alert when hitting submit

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have the following function to show a alert when the visitor hits "cancel" or trying to go back with filled textfields. The function works perfectly overall but not when I'm hit submit. The alert shows when I hit the button and I don't want it that way.

```
var changed_flag = 0;

$('input').change(function() {
    changed_flag = 1;
});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    if(changed_flag) {
        return 'You haven't saved your work!'
    }
};
```

I know I should edit the `$('input').change(...` and add `input[type="submit"]` but I don't know how and where. Do anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    changed_flag = 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for copying my answer instead of submitting a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    $(window).unbind('beforeunload');
});
```

Alternatively instead of the unbind you could just do `changed_flag = 0`

Comment: That function didn't work at all :/ How do I add `changed_flag = 0` to it?

Comment: @Erik: You put `changed_flag = 0;` in the `submit` event handler, just like you have `changed_flag = 1;` in the `change` event handler.

Comment: @FelixKling: Like this: `...(function() { changed_flag = 0 });`?

Answer (score 0):

Just have your submit button remove the event or set changed_flag back to 0.

```
<input type="submit" onmousedown="changed_flag = 0" />
```

EDIT: On second thoughts put this code in your onsubmit handler in case the form is submitted some other way (like pressing enter or via another function).

Comment: bad practice to put event handlers on your html tags, and this won't work for things like pressing enter to submit the form